# Remove specific characters from a long string Typescript

Tags: typescript

this does not makes sense, how to remove the specific chars from the string?

Code bellow don't work

Thanks

```
var CamlQuer = "{"$o_1":true,"$N_1":"<View><ViewFields><FieldRef Name=\"Title\" /><FieldRef Name=\"Date1\" /></ViewFields><Joins><Join Type=\"LEFT\" ListAlias=\"Workshop\"><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"WorkshopResult\" RefType=\"ID\" /><FieldRef Name=\"ID\" List=\"Workshop\" /></Eq></Join></Joins><ProjectedFields><Field ShowField=\"Workshop\" Type=\"Lookup\" Name=\"Title\" List=\"Workshop\" /></ProjectedFields><Query><Where /></Query></View>"}"

camlQuer.split('"$o_1":true,"$N_1":"').join('');
console.log(camlQuer);
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like part of the problem is your `CamlQuer` needs additional escapes and to match the casing of `camlQuer` below.

Next, the [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method does not modify the variable directly, so you need to reassign the output.

These change would make your code look like:

```js
var camlQuer = "{\"$o_1\":true,\"$N_1\":\"<View><ViewFields><FieldRef Name=\"Title\" /><FieldRef Name=\"Date1\" /></ViewFields><Joins><Join Type=\"LEFT\" ListAlias=\"Workshop\"><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"WorkshopResult\" RefType=\"ID\" /><FieldRef Name=\"ID\" List=\"Workshop\" /></Eq></Join></Joins><ProjectedFields><Field ShowField=\"Workshop\" Type=\"Lookup\" Name=\"Title\" List=\"Workshop\" /></ProjectedFields><Query><Where /></Query></View>\"}"

camlQuer = camlQuer.split('"$o_1":true,"$N_1":"').join('');
console.log(camlQuer)
```

However, you would be better off using the [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method which is meant to remove or replace a string of characters. Your code would then look like:

```js
var camlQuer = "{\"$o_1\":true,\"$N_1\":\"<View><ViewFields><FieldRef Name=\"Title\" /><FieldRef Name=\"Date1\" /></ViewFields><Joins><Join Type=\"LEFT\" ListAlias=\"Workshop\"><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"WorkshopResult\" RefType=\"ID\" /><FieldRef Name=\"ID\" List=\"Workshop\" /></Eq></Join></Joins><ProjectedFields><Field ShowField=\"Workshop\" Type=\"Lookup\" Name=\"Title\" List=\"Workshop\" /></ProjectedFields><Query><Where /></Query></View>\"}"

camlQuer = camlQuer.replace('"$o_1":true,"$N_1":"', '');
console.log(camlQuer)
```

Comment: Hi Nick, this is only a JSON.stringify() from an object, adding specific escapes is not an option. With escapes or not is only a string. If I can’t handle this maybe is a good option to try to remove directly from the object that will be the optimal behaviour. Can you help me with that?

Comment: If you are using `JSON.stringify` then the escapes should be correct in the code and incorrectly placed in the question.

Answer (score 0):

My approach in order to "escape" the string

```
let regexp = new RegExp(camlQuer);
```

Using Nick solution

```
let regexp = new RegExp(camlQuer);
console.log(camlQuer);
camlQuer = camlQuer.replace('"$o_1":true,"$N_1":"', '');
```